# Help manual partitioning for installing ubuntu alongside win 7

Tags: partitioning

I have windows7 installed on c drive . It has 5 gb free.There're other 2 drives. D with 110 gb free. E with 298 free. What is a sensible way to do manual partitioning to run ubuntu alongside with win 7 ?

Comment: You could try to automatic partition feature in the graphic installer. Or click on manuell and use empty partitions as ext4 and mounting point /

Comment: They don't recommend it , do they ?

Comment: Who does not recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Based on youre needs. I don't know about youre existing partitions Preferably that swap and system should be on different devices. For example if you don't override MBR limits(4 primary parts per one table) or you have GPT you can create 50gb part for "/" from disk D and 4gb swap on disk E(you will see them as /dev/sda, /dev/sdb... All other free space you can use as you want.

Comment: could you make it any simpler. Well, I'm a starter for linux

Comment: Yes, but you should tell me about your current partitions first. In Win7 You can see information about them in Computer Management -> Disk Management.

Comment: windows 7(c:) 50 gb NTFS 5 gb free. (D:) 200 gb, 110 gb free. (E:) 345gb, 298free. all NTFS

Comment: Need info about all devices

Comment: please review the edit

Comment: You can't create partitions on "free space". You need "unallocated space". So you should resize any of NTFS partitions to get unallocated space for partitioning. Or you can erase one.

Comment: Are there any chances of losing data while shrinking or resizing the drive ?

Comment: Yes. Data can corrupt by IO error or power down. So it little risky if you haven't UPS. I should clarify. All these partitions on the same hard drive or on different? If on the same you can't have vore then 4 primary partitions (you need 1 for system and 1 for swap) so you should delete one existing.

Comment: If you don't want use resizing/shrinking you can copy data from part D to part E. Then while install Ubuntu you should delete part D(now empty) and create 2 parts: 4gb for swap and other unallocated space for root( / )